# Merge two rows in UNIX using Sed / Awk

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, sed

Consider source file in UNIX with below pipe delimited rows. This example has five rows. Row # 1,2,and 4 are good but Row # 3 and 5 split into two rows because of newline in the text. I have to merge line 3 into single row and line 5 into single row by removing new line only at t and then load into oracle table.

How this can be achieved using sed / awk or any other UNIX command?

#### Example for input:

```
 1. 9187-001|COS 60W 16G T1A CLV|||||10  
 2. 9184-002|COS 48W 28G NT SKO|FOOTAGE/SEQUENCE GRIDS||||10  
 3. 9679-229|COS 56G 40G NT SVO|"FOOTAGE/SEQUENCE GRIDS FOR STREETSCAPE STORES  
(ALL COSMETICS ON 60"" HIGH GONDOLAS"||||10  
 4. 9184-230|COS48W 48G NT LIF SKO|LIFE STORE COSMETIC FOOTAGE/SEQUENCE GRID||||10  
 5. 9679-230|COS 56G 44G NT SVO|"FOOTAGE/SEQUENCE GRIDS FOR STREETSCAPE STORES  
(ALL COSMETICS ON 60"" HIGH GONDOLAS"||||10
```

#### Desired output:

```
1. 9187-001|COS 60W 16G T1A CLV|||||10  
2. 9184-002|COS 48W 28G NT SKO|FOOTAGE/SEQUENCE GRIDS||||10  
3. 9679-229|COS 56G 40G NT SVO|"FOOTAGE/SEQUENCE GRIDS FOR STREETSCAPE STORES(ALL COSMETICS ON 60"" HIGH GONDOLAS"||||10  
4. 9184-230|COS48W 48G NT LIF SKO|LIFE STORE COSMETIC FOOTAGE/SEQUENCE GRID||||10  
5. 9679-230|COS 56G 44G NT SVO|"FOOTAGE/SEQUENCE GRIDS FOR STREETSCAPE STORES(ALL COSMETICS ON 60"" HIGH GONDOLAS"||||10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{gsub(/\s*\n\(/,"(")}1' file
 1. 9187-001|COS 60W 16G T1A CLV|||||10
 2. 9184-002|COS 48W 28G NT SKO|FOOTAGE/SEQUENCE GRIDS||||10
 3. 9679-229|COS 56G 40G NT SVO|"FOOTAGE/SEQUENCE GRIDS FOR STREETSCAPE STORES(ALL COSMETICS ON 60"" HIGH GONDOLAS"||||10
 4. 9184-230|COS48W 48G NT LIF SKO|LIFE STORE COSMETIC FOOTAGE/SEQUENCE GRID||||10
 5. 9679-230|COS 56G 44G NT SVO|"FOOTAGE/SEQUENCE GRIDS FOR STREETSCAPE STORES(ALL COSMETICS ON 60"" HIGH GONDOLAS"||||10
```

Answer (score 1):

Through perl,

```
perl -00pe 's/\n(?!\h*\d)//g' file
```

OR

```
$ perl -00pe 's/\n(?=\()//g' file
 1. 9187-001|COS 60W 16G T1A CLV|||||10  
 2. 9184-002|COS 48W 28G NT SKO|FOOTAGE/SEQUENCE GRIDS||||10  
 3. 9679-229|COS 56G 40G NT SVO|"FOOTAGE/SEQUENCE GRIDS FOR STREETSCAPE STORES(ALL COSMETICS ON 60"" HIGH GONDOLAS"||||10  
 4. 9184-230|COS48W 48G NT LIF SKO|LIFE STORE COSMETIC FOOTAGE/SEQUENCE GRID||||10  
 5. 9679-230|COS 56G 44G NT SVO|"FOOTAGE/SEQUENCE GRIDS FOR STREETSCAPE STORES(ALL COSMETICS ON 60"" HIGH GONDOLAS"||||10
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that each line should have 7 fields:

```
awk -F'|' '
    {$0 = prev $0} 
    NF < 7 {prev = $0} 
    NF == 7 {print; prev=""}
' file
```

But really, you should be using a proper CSV parser:

```
perl -MText::CSV -Mautodie -E '
    $csv = Text::CSV->new({binary => 1, sep_char => "|", quote_space => 0});
    open $fh, "<", shift;
    while ($row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
        $csv->combine( map {s/\n//g; $_} @$row );
        say $csv->string();
    }
' file
```

```
 1. 9187-001|COS 60W 16G T1A CLV|||||10  
 2. 9184-002|COS 48W 28G NT SKO|FOOTAGE/SEQUENCE GRIDS||||10  
 3. 9679-229|COS 56G 40G NT SVO|"FOOTAGE/SEQUENCE GRIDS FOR STREETSCAPE STORES  (ALL COSMETICS ON 60"" HIGH GONDOLAS"||||10  
 4. 9184-230|COS48W 48G NT LIF SKO|LIFE STORE COSMETIC FOOTAGE/SEQUENCE GRID||||10  
 5. 9679-230|COS 56G 44G NT SVO|"FOOTAGE/SEQUENCE GRIDS FOR STREETSCAPE STORES  (ALL COSMETICS ON 60"" HIGH GONDOLAS"||||10
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in awk, as well

```
awk '{if(!match($0,"[0-9]\\. ")){print prev$0}else{print $0}; prev=$0}' file
```

Comment: you don't need match just to test for a match, you only need it when you want to use RSTART/RLENGTH afterwards. The 2nd arg for `match()` is a regexp not a string so use regexp delimiters and then you won't need to double escape anything `match($0,/[0-9]\. /)`. You don't need to specify `$0` as an arg to `print` as that's the default. You whole command could be reduced to `awk '{print (/[0-9]\. /?"":prev) $0; prev=$0}' file` (but it still would not produce the desired output).

Comment: Yes, you are right. It gives duplicate rows, so I would replace it with something like `awk '{if(!match($0,"[0-9]\\. ")){printf $0}else{printf "\n"$0}; prev=$0};END{printf "\n"}'`, but I must admit that Glenn Jackmans' solution is simpler and more elegant. As to your remarks, I like to specify default arguments, as it seems to make code clearer, but thanks for information on regexp delimiters in `match()`.

Comment: Never do `printf $0`, always do `printf "%s", $0` instead. Imagine the difference if `$0` contained `%s` or some other printf formatting string. That should fit well with your philosophy of specifying all of the args regardless of whether or not they are needed. You also don't need those spurious semi-colons.